# Use of go's struct pointer as interface

Tags: go

I want to pass struct method as function value. Why does compilation fail if function is required to return interface{} and it returns *struct? It perfectly works if I try to return *struct from function that is declared to return interface{} (wrapper func).

```
package main

func main() {
        println("hello")
        testInterface(wrapper)          // works
        instance := MyStruct{}
        testInterface(instance.works)   // works
        testInterface(instance.fails)   // fails: ./main.go:8: cannot use instance.fails (type func(int) *MyStruct) as type func(int) interface {} in argument to testInterface
}

func testInterface(f func() interface{}) {
        f()
        return
}

type MyStruct struct {
}

func (s *MyStruct) works() interface{} {
        return s
}

func (s *MyStruct) fails() *MyStruct {
        return s
}

func wrapper() interface{} {
        s := MyStruct{}
        return s.fails()
```

}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because it does not fit the [assignability](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Assignability) criterias

> A value `x` is assignable to a variable of type `T` ("`x` is assignable to `T`") in any of these cases:
>
> - `x`'s type is identical to `T`.
> - `x`'s type `V` and `T` have identical underlying types and at least one of `V` or `T` is not a named type.
> - `T` is an interface type and `x` implements `T`.
> - `x` is a bidirectional channel value, `T` is a channel type, `x`'s type `V` and `T` have identical element types, and at least one of `V` or `T` is not a named type.
> - `x` is the predeclared identifier `nil` and `T` is a pointer, function, slice, map, channel, or interface type.
> - `x` is an untyped constant representable by a value of type `T`.

So, this explains why `testInterface(instance.fails)` fails: because the `instance.fails` is not assignable to the `f func() interface{}`.

Now the second question:

> It perfectly works if I try to return *struct from function that is declared to return interface{} (wrapper func).

It works fine, because the value of the `*struct` type is assignable to the `interface{}` type because of:

1. this rule of the assignability: "`T` is an interface type and `x` implements `T`."
2. "A type implements any interface comprising any subset of its methods and may therefore implement several distinct interfaces. For instance, **all types implement the empty interface**:" (bold is mine)

References:

- [Type identity](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_identity)
- [Assignability](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Assignability)
- [Interface types](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Interface_types)